# Equivalent rewriting of a probability event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I would like your help to understand where is the mistake in the following reasonings which involve probabilities.

Consider a model where an individual can choose among 3 options. Each option $i$ gives reward $a_i+\epsilon_i$ and the individual chooses the option with highest reward. Each $\epsilon_i$ is an absolutely continuous random variable and $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3$ are mutually independent. Each $a_i$ is a constant number (not random).

Hence,
$$
(1) \quad \Pr(\text{choosing }1)= \Pr(a_1+\epsilon_1\geq a_2+\epsilon_2 \text{ and }a_1+\epsilon_1\geq a_3+\epsilon_3)
$$
For example, if each $\epsilon_i$ is [Gumbel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) with scale 1 and location 0, we get
$$
(2) \quad \Pr(\text{choosing }1)= \frac{\exp(a_1)}{\exp(a_1)+\exp(a_2)+\exp(a_3)}
$$
Now, if I look at (1), it seems to me equivalent to writing
$$
(3) \quad \Pr(\text{choosing }1)= \Pr(a_1+\epsilon_1\geq a_2+\epsilon_2\geq a_3+\epsilon_3 \text{ or }a_1+\epsilon_1\geq a_3+\epsilon_3\geq a_2+\epsilon_2)\\
= \Pr(a_1+\epsilon_1\geq a_2+\epsilon_2\geq a_3+\epsilon_3)+ \Pr(a_1+\epsilon_1\geq a_3+\epsilon_3\geq a_2+\epsilon_2)
$$
Is this last equality correct? If yes, can you prove that, under the Gumbel distribution, we get (2) from (3)?

Comment: As if say $a_1 = 10$, $a_2 = a_3 = 0$ then (2) gives you probability of greater than 1, so it's definitely not correct. How did you got it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. There was a typo. It is from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression

Comment: I have never heard of Gumbel, but the equalities in (3) look correct to me (assuming that $Pr(a_2 + \epsilon_2 = a_3 + \epsilon_3) = 0$).  If you plug in Gumbel in (3), what do you get and how is it different from (2)?

Comment: Showing that is part of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do get $(2)$ from $(3)$ in the case of standard Gumbel random variables.

Indeed, the random variable $T_i = \exp(-\epsilon_i)$ are independent and exponential with parameter $1$. By conditionning with regard to $T_2$, we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
Pr[a_1+\epsilon_1 \ge a_2+\epsilon_2 \ge a_3+\epsilon_3]
&=& Pr[e^{-a_1}T_1 \le e^{-a_2}T_2 \le e^{-a_3}T_3)] \\
&=& Pr[T_1 \le e^{a_1-a_2}T_2 ; T_3 \ge e^{a_3-a_2}T_2]\\
&=& E\big[\big(1-\exp(-e^{a_1-a_2}T_2)\big) \exp(-e^{a_3-a_2}T_2)\big]\\
&=& E[\exp(-e^{a_3-a_2}T_2)] - E[\exp(-(e^{a_1-a_2}+e^{a_3-a_2})T_2)] \\
&=& \frac{1}{1+e^{a_3-a_2}} - \frac{1}{1+e^{a_1-a_2}+e^{a_3-a_2}} \\
&=& \frac{e^{a_2}}{e^{a_2}+e^{a_3}} - \frac{e^{a_2}}{e^{a_2}+e^{a_1}+e^{a_3}} \\
&=& \frac{e^{a_2}e^{a_1}}{(e^{a_2}+e^{a_3})(e^{a_2}+e^{a_1}+e^{a_3})}
\end{eqnarray*}
In a same way,
$$Pr[a_1+\epsilon_1 \ge a_3+\epsilon_3 \ge a_2+\epsilon_2] = \frac{e^{a_3}e^{a_1}}{(e^{a_2}+e^{a_3})(e^{a_2}+e^{a_1}+e^{a_3})}.$$
The sum of these two probabilities is $$\frac{e^{a_2}}{e^{a_2}+e^{a_1}+e^{a_3}},$$
as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide a reference for the fact that $T_i$ is exponential?

Comment: Also, how do you compute, for instance, $E(\exp(-e^{(a_3-a_2)}T_2)$?

Comment: Use that for all $t>0$, $P[T_i \ge t] = P[\epsilon_i \le -\ln t]$. The Laplace transform of $T_i$ is easily computed from its density: for every $\lambda>-1$, $$E[e^{-\lambda T_i}] = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} e^{-t} dt = \frac{1}{1+\lambda}.$$